# Bash: Use exec find option by sorting two file arguments

Tags: bash, find, sort

Let's say I want to compare the files with the same filename between these two directories:

```
 /tmp/datadir/dir1/dir2/
```

and

```
 /datadir/dir1/dir2/
```

It is required to **sort** them before comparing.

I am currently in the `/tmp` directory, and I tried to run this `find` with the `exec` option:

```
find datadir -type f -exec sdiff -s <( sort {} ) <( sort "/"{} ) \;
```

But, it gives me an error

> sort: open failed: {}: No such file or directory
>
> sort: open failed: /{}: No such file or directory

However, the below command works fine, but the data is not sorted for proper comparison.

```
find data -type f -exec sdiff -s  {}  "/"{} \;
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The replacement of `{}` is done by `find` and happens after the evaluation of the process substitution (`<(…)`) and such in your code.

Using `bash -c`:

```
find datadir -type f -exec \
  bash -c 'sdiff -s <( sort "$1" ) <( sort "/$1" )' bash {} \;
```

Or to avoid running one `bash` instance per file:

```
find datadir -type f -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    sdiff -s <( sort "$file" ) <( sort "/$file" )
  done' bash {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the `-r` (recursive) option that does all the sorting and recursing for you.